# How to change the SFMCSdk configuration during runtime?

Tags: marketing-cloud, android

Our SFMCSdk is initialized when the user is logged in and we clear the parameters and disable push when logging out.

On iOS there seems to be `sfmc_tearDown` to release the current instance, which lets you change the configuration.

How do we do the same thing on Android? I could not find any tear down method and when I call `SFMCSdk.configure()` again the app just crashes:

> (pool-33-thread-1) > ☠☠☠ FATAL ☠☠☠
> Message: Task com.salesforce.marketingcloud.events.c$a@540bc21 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@8685846[Shutting
> down, pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed
> tasks = 5]
> Stacktrace: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task com.salesforce.marketingcloud.events.c$a@540bc21 rejected from
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@8685846[Shutting down, pool
> size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 5]
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2086)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:848)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1394)
> at java.util.concurrent.Executors$DelegatedExecutorService.execute(Executors.java:630)
> at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.events.c.a(Unknown Source:25)
> at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.events.c$d.a(Unknown Source:24)
> at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.internal.g.run(Unknown Source:17)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been resolved.  Please update to version 8.0.3 of the SDK.  At the moment there is no `tearDown` in the Android SDK.

Comment: I tested the 8.0.3 today and I am getting the same crash with `RejectedExecutionException` when calling `SFMCSdk.configure()` a second time.

Would it be possible to get a more detailed list of the fixes/improvements for the version?

Comment: Please open a support request through your account manager.

Comment: I am able to call `configure` multiple times without incident.

Comment: Ok I kind of figured out some bug from our side led to SFMCSdk being configured and edited (profileId/parameters) twice in parallel. Fixing it will most probably fix my `RejectedExecutionException`.

Comment: I would be very interested in the steps to reproduce this issue.  If it is readily reproducible then we can probably protect against this in the future.